# Ignore commented out tags when read xml file using tinyxml library in c++

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

When i read xml file using c++, the commented out tags read also and i want to ignore it
i.e:

```
<tag>-------</tag>
<tag>-------</tag>
<!--<tag>-------</tag> -->
<!--
<tag>-------</tag>
<tag>-------</tag>
<tag>-------</tag>
 -->
<tag>-------</tag>
```

Comment: Please, have a look into the XML spec. [**Comments**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-comments): _For compatibility, the string "--" (double-hyphen) must not occur within comments._ Maybe, this is your issue with tinyxml...